# Is there any bad side effects for using calcium chloride to replace a running dehumidifier?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

My dehumidifier costs to much to run, so I’m thinking about using calcium chloride to keep my basement dry(er) ALSO, this **may** keep my mouse problem to a minimum... my questions are -Will this be harmful to me breathing this when I’m in the basement?
-Will any gases be omitted to me in my main floor? 
-Will this remove to much moisture that my block foundation will start to degrade?
-Are there any other side effects I’m not aware of?
The only person that goes in basement is me so I’m not concerned about anyone consuming it.

Comment: It is only harmful when eaten (and even then, not much), won't release any gases, and I don't believe you can remove too much moisture this way or any other way. That said, why do you think it is cheaper?

Comment: @IvanNeretin - perhaps they are ignoring the fact they will need to dry the material over and over again in an oven? Of course, filling the basement with calcium chloride is a good way to stop worrying about the humidity levels there...

Comment: ...for a while.

Comment: Actually, some commercial products intended for room drying are made of calcium chloride (scented, in some cases), so no worries. I guess it works when humidity is relatively contained, anyway: it is cheap, but you can't expect the performance of an electric dehumidifier without buying a lot of it

Answer (score 3):

As for safety, calcium chloride, $\ce{CaCl2}$, is in sea water and [added to foods](https://bakerpedia.com/ingredients/calcium-chloride/), such as beans and pickles. It's about as dangerous as table salt, sodium chloride, $\ce{NaCl}$ (actually, $\ce{CaCl2}$ is safer for concrete).

However, it absorbs only so much water until it dissolves and stops being effective. What would you do with the puddle of $\ce{CaCl2}$ solution? It *can* be dried with heat and reused, but then your just moving energy usage from a continually running electric dehumidifier to a batch process using $\ce{CaCl2}$... though if you can get heat for free, it would be cost effective! If you don't have a solar concentrator or access to geothermal energy, there would probably be no energy savings, though.

Comment: Concrete samples have been rapidly destroyed when
stored in CaCl2 solutions under certain conditions (Peterson, 1991). The most critical
concentration and temperature seems to be 30 % and 5 °C, respectively. [Peterson, C.: The chemical effects on cement mortar of solutions of calcium
Magnesium acetate and other deicing salts, Report TVBM-3045, Lund Institute of
Technology, Sweden.]

Comment: @user482745, thank you for that concrete info. How does that compare with immersion in NaCl solution?